# How to auto-size column-width in Excel during text entry

Tags: excel, vba, column-width

I usually try to avoid VBA in Excel, but it would be convenient to be able to type text into a cell, and have its column get wider or narrower to accommodate the text remaining as it's entered or deleted.

This would be subject, of course, to the lengths of the text in the other cells in the column.

'Auto-fit as you type', I guess you might call it.

Is there an easy way to do this in a suitable handler?

Comment: You can't have autofit *as* you type, but you can have autofit as soon as you're finished typing and exit the cell.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do it while you're typing.  I think Excel generally stretches the cell view to display all the text before it fires the worksheet_change event.

This code will resize the column after you have changed and moved the target to a new range.  Place it in the worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim nextTarget As Range
    
    Set nextTarget = Range(Selection.Address) 'store the next range the user selects
    
    Target.Columns.Select 'autofit requires columns to be selected
    Target.Columns.AutoFit
    
    nextTarget.Select
End Sub
```

If you're looking to do it for a particular column, you would need to check the target column like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim nextTarget As Range
    
    Set nextTarget = Range(Selection.Address) 'store the next range the user selects
    
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
    
        Target.Columns.Select 'autofit requires columns to be selected
        Target.Columns.AutoFit
    
        nextTarget.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern versions of Excel (2010+, I don't know about the 2007 version) you could use a macro to resize your column to fit data as soon you finish entering data in a cell.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Put the macro in the `ThisWorkbook` module

Comment: This is the correct format for `Workbook_SheetChange`. [Both _Sh_ and _Target_ are required parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange).

Answer (score 0):

This will automatically fit columns width

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, I verified it works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target Is Nothing Then
      Exit Sub
    Else
      With Target
        .Columns.Select
        .Columns.AutoFit
      End With
End If
End Sub
```